# Evaluating $\int _0^{\infty }e^{x\left(t-p\right)}p^{1-e^{-px}}\:dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, gamma-function

How do I proceed with this integration? When I try integration by parts, the same thing keeps coming over and over again.

$$I=\int_0^\infty e^{x(t-p)}p^{1-e^{-px}}\,dx$$

Comment: thanks @Mark for the editing.

Comment: I am not going to try that particular integral!  But what do you mean by "the same thing keeps coming over and over again"?   If you mean that, using "integration by parts", you got something like $\int udv= uv- \int vdu$ and it happens that $\int vdu$ is the same as $\Int udv$, then that is [tex\\int udv= uv- \int udv$.  So add $\int udv$ to both sidex: $2\int udv= uv$, $\int= \frac{1}{2}uv$.

Comment: yes, when I integrate by parts, the second term that you mentioned is actually an integral of the form of I. I cannot add the term you asked because the recurring term is not exactly the same one, but with slight changes in the constants in exponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok lets start evaluating this:
$$\int _0^{\infty }e^{x\left(t-p\right)}\:p^{1-e^{-px}}\:dx=p\underbrace{\int _0^{\infty }e^{tx}\:e^{-px}\:p^{-e^{-px}}\:dx}_{u=e^{-px}}$$
$$=\int _0^1u^{-\frac{t}{p}}\:\:p^{-u}\:du=\underbrace{\int _0^1u^{-\frac{t}{p}}\:\:e^{-u\ln \left(p\right)}\:du}_{x=u\ln \left(p\right)}$$
$$\ln \left(p\right)^{\frac{t}{p}-1}\int _0^{\ln \left(p\right)}x^{-\frac{t}{p}}\:\:e^{-x}\:dx$$
As you may notice thats the definition of the lower incomplete gamma function.
$$\int _0^xt^{z-1}\:e^{-t}\:dt=\gamma \left(z,x\right)$$
Also lets use the fact that,
$$\gamma \:\left(z,x\right)=\Gamma \left(z\right)-\Gamma \left(z,x\right)$$
So your integral,
$$\ln \left(p\right)^{\frac{t}{p}-1}\gamma \left(1-\frac{t}{p},\ln \left(p\right)\right)\:=\ln \left(p\right)^{\frac{t}{p}-1}\left(\Gamma \left(1-\frac{t}{p}\right)-\Gamma \left(1-\frac{t}{p},\ln \left(p\right)\right)\right)$$
To finalize lets use this identity involving the exponential integral,
$$E_n\left(x\right)=x^{n-1}\Gamma \left(1-n,x\right)$$
So,
$$\ln \left(p\right)^{\frac{t}{p}-1}\left(\Gamma \left(1-\frac{t}{p}\right)-\frac{E_{\frac{t}{p}}\left(\ln \left(p\right)\right)}{\ln \left(p\right)^{\frac{t}{p}-1}}\right)$$
Simplifying a bit we arrive at the solution of your integral,
$$\boxed{\int _0^{\infty }e^{x\left(t-p\right)}\:p^{1-e^{-px}}\:dx=\ln \left(p\right)^{\frac{t}{p}-1}\Gamma \left(1-\frac{t}{p}\right)-E_{\frac{t}{p}}\left(\ln \left(p\right)\right)}$$

Comment: Okay so this comes down to be an incomplete gamma integral, but recently I was working on a similar problem, only that the $e$ from the gamma distribution was replaced by another constant value. How do I proceed then?